# how to rename existing menu item?

Tags: android

Do you know how to rename existing menu ?

I can rename when press menu item. But I don't know how to access to menu item when press the button.

Please advice.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You seem to be confusing the terms 'menu', 'menu item' and perhaps 'button'.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It would be good if you can clarify the question a little, but each time the user presses the <kbd>Menu</kbd> on their Android device while inside one of your activities, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method is called.  The first time the menu is shown (i.e. *only once*), the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is called.

Basically, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method is where you should make any changes such as enabling/disabling certain menu items, or changing the menu item text depending on the circumstances.

As an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Check current message count
    boolean haveMessages = mMessageCount != 0;

    // Set 'delete' menu item state depending on count
    MenuItem deleteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete);
    deleteItem.setTitle(haveMessages ? R.string.delete : R.string.no_messages);
    deleteItem.setEnabled(haveMessages);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I've found the solution : public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) 
it would be fine for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MenuItem.setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle(int)).  If this isn't what you needed, you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The onPrepareOptionsMenu is the proper place to make changes to menuitems.

Comment: From the docs it would seem so. Any idea what the onMenuOpened method could be used for? I can also change my menu in it.